# onclick attribute of button specified in JavaScript doesn't visible in html inspect

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-4

i have made a code where made a button named "Clear Cart" and passes it to the html code via javascript. I added the attribute 'onclick' on that button but when I inspect that button on page then button appears without 'onclick' attribute. All other attributes are appearing okay but 'onclick' attribute is not visible there.
this is my code:

```
popStr = popStr + "<button id ='clearcart' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='clearCart()'> Clear Cart </button>";
document.getElementById('popcart').setAttribute('data-content', popStr);
```

This is the output I am receiving

````
<button id="clearcart" class="btn btn-primary"> Clear Cart </button>```
````

Comment: How is it getting actually added to the DOM after being taken from the data attribute? Or do you mean that it is missing from the data attribute value?

Comment: What is the initial value of `popStr`? And please post relevant code snippets of your HTML too.

Comment: Personally I am against injecting HTML directly into elements and would got for a (much more) readable answer as: `let btn =  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button')); btn.className = 'btn btn-primary'; btn.id = 'clearcart'; btn.onlick = clearCart; btn.innerText = 'Clear cart';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your html is "sanitized" (removing the onclick) by the library you are using to inject the new element.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about how it is added to the DOM from `data-content` attribute. There should not be any problem if you are setting this HTML from data attribute to DOM with [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Following is the sample code based on the assumptions:

```
let popStr = "";

popStr = popStr + "<button id ='clearcart' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='clearCart()'> Clear Cart </button>";

document.getElementById('popcart').setAttribute('data-content', popStr);

function addToDom() {
   document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = document.getElementById('popcart').dataset.content;
}

function clearCart() {
  alert("working!")
}
```

Workign example: https://jsbin.com/tavoyozewa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you should consider using `let` or `const` instead of `var` for cleaner javascript codes